# MeteorJS AccountTemplates Custom Field Stuck at Required Error

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I've encountered this weird behaviour from the atSignUp Template in Meteor's useraccounts package, I've added a custom field using the regular way and set the Required field to true, However on the webapp this specific field only gets stuck showing the error message "Required Field", even if I change the selection. I'm using useraccounts:semantic-ui as well, I've looked everywhere can't seem to find a solution.

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
  _id: "gender",
  type: "select",
  displayName: "Gender",
  required: true,
  select: [
    {
        text: "Male",
        value: "male",
    },
    {
        text: "Female",
        value: "female",
    }
  ]
}); //gender field
```

[Screenshot of the occurrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaQDN.png)

Answer (score 0):

After looking around more, I've managed to hack a solution. by using Aldeed:meteor-template-extension Event Handler Template.OnRendered() and put a default selection value using jQuery selector on the id of the hidden input field of the dropdown menu.

```
Template.onRendered(function () {
    //resolves the registration form gender selection issue
    const selectGender = $('#at-field-gender');
    if(selectGender.length){
        selectGender.val('male');
    }
});
```